# printf epochtime shows wrong values

Tags: c, format-specifiers, time-t

I am experimenting with `time_t` variables, and this is the code in question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct tm epochtime;
time_t epochdate;

int main()
{
  epochtime.tm_mday = 19;
  epochtime.tm_mon = 10;
  epochtime.tm_year = 2002;
  epochtime.tm_hour = 0;
  epochtime.tm_min = 0;
  epochtime.tm_sec = 0 ;
  
  epochdate = mktime(&epochtime);

  printf("%ju\n",epochdate);
  printf("%ju\n", (uint32_t)epochdate);
  printf("%ju\n", (uint64_t)epochdate);
  printf("%ju\n", (uintmax_t)epochdate);
  printf("%Lf\n", epochdate);
  printf("%Le\n", epochdate);
}
```

I am trying to print the `epochtime` of a given date. The code compiles and has no errors, but when I compare what I get printed to what I calculate on [this website](https://www.epochconverter.com/), the values are not the same. For this given values in the example above the code output is:

```
210453397503
210453397503
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
-1.#QNAN0e+000
-1.#QNAN0e
```

while the link says that value should be `1034985600`. I have tried multiple `printf` format specifiers because I found multiple answers here on how to print `time_t` variables, but none of them seems to work for me. Any ideas why?

Comment: `18446744073709551615` is `(uint64_t)-1` ... apparently your `mktime()` is returning `-1`: [C11 7.27.2.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.2.3) -- "If the calendar time cannot be represented, the function returns the value (time_t)(-1)."

Comment: Maybe you need to shift the year (1900 years back) and month (1 month back), ... and pay attention to DST?

Comment: First step should always be the man page: *" **`tm_year`** Year (current year minus 1900)."*

Comment: @pmg  for the month, I was keeping the -1 shift in mind when calculating. I looked at the exact definition of struct tm and the link I have didnt specify that year is calculated since 1900. your suggestion worked btw, Thank you !

Comment: @WeatherVane the link I looked at didn#t specify it that's why I missed that info. but the shift in years corrected the results. thank you!

Comment: In that case do you need to find a better reference? [This page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime) describes `struct tm` and mentions the ranges a bit further down. I generally use the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crt-alphabetical-function-reference?view=msvc-160&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019) because I use MSVC.

Comment: @pmg However I am trying this on 2 compilers an online compiler and codeblocks. codeblocks still gives me wrong values even after modifying the values. do you have an idea why?

Comment: @WeatherVane I am new to coding, I am trying different small codes on different compilers. the code above after correction worked on an online compiler but not on codeblocks, it still prints wrong values. any idea why?

Comment: `printf("%Le\n", epochdate);` enable all compiler warnings and listen to them.

Comment: `printf("%Lf\n", epochdate);` is unlikely to "work" on any compiler.

Comment: In `printf("%ju\n", (uint32_t)epochdate);` the `j` tells `printf` that you are passing type `uintmax_t` but you are not – it's `uint32_t` so that too is *undefined behaviour*. Please see [Format specification syntax: printf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions).

Comment: The `printf()` and `scanf()` function family are very involved: it is not a trivial exercise to explore them. It's made harder by the fact that they seem similar, but have some significant differences.

Comment: @WeatherVane I am confused... what is the correct format specifier to print epochdate then??

Comment: `printf("%ju\n", (uintmax_t)epochdate);` should be good. But you must check the `-1` result first.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes it worked finally, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you want to represent the date: October 19th, 2002 00:00:00, which corresponds to the epoch timestamp that you expect: 1034985600.

In such case, you are doing it wrong. Read [the manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mktime.3.html):

> Broken-down time is stored in the structure `tm`, which is defined in `<time.h>` as follows:
>
> ```
> struct tm {
>     int tm_sec;    /* Seconds (0-60) */
>     int tm_min;    /* Minutes (0-59) */
>     int tm_hour;   /* Hours (0-23) */
>     int tm_mday;   /* Day of the month (1-31) */
>     int tm_mon;    /* Month (0-11) */
>     int tm_year;   /* Year - 1900 */
>     int tm_wday;   /* Day of the week (0-6, Sunday = 0) */
>     int tm_yday;   /* Day in the year (0-365, 1 Jan = 0) */
>     int tm_isdst;  /* Daylight saving time */
> };
> ```

Your year should be 2002 - 1900 = 102, and your month should be 9, not 10 (months start from 0 = January).

The correct code is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void) {
    struct tm epochtime = {
        .tm_mday = 19,
        .tm_mon = 9,
        .tm_year = 102,
        .tm_hour = 0,
        .tm_min = 0,
        .tm_sec = 0,
        .tm_isdst = -1
    };

    time_t epochdate = mktime(&epochtime);
    if (epochdate == (time_t)(-1)) {
        perror("mktime failed");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("%" PRIuMAX "\n", (uintmax_t)epochdate);
    return 0;
}
```

Which correctly outputs `1034985600` as you expect.

The problem with your code is most likely that `mktime` is not able to correctly represent the "wrong" date you provide and returns `-1`, which you then print as unsigned and becomes a huge nonsensical number.

Answer (score 0):

> printf epochtime shows wrong values

There is no specified matching *print specifier* for `time_t`.  All the `printf()` except `printf("%ju\n", (uintmax_t)epochdate);` can lead to *undefined behavior* (UB).

> ... multiple answers here on how to print time-t variables, but none of them seems to work for me. Any ideas why?

`time_t` is a type capable of representing times.

> The range and precision of times representable in `clock_t` and `time_t` are implementation-defined.  C17dr § 7.27.1 4

---

Print using a cast.  As `time_t` is *very* commonly a signed integer type, cast to a wide *signed* type:

```
time_t t;
time(&t);
printf("%jd", (intmax_t) t);
// or pre-C99
printf("%ld", (long) t);
```

or for wide portability at the small risk of losing some precision,

```
printf("%f", (double) t);
```

---

`printf("%ju\n", (uintmax_t)epochdate);`  --> 18446744073709551615 is certainly the result of `mktime(&epochtime);` returning -1 due to a conversion error, likely due to range error with `epochtime.tm_year = 2002;`.  `.tm_year` is the year *since* 1900.  [@pmg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64630721/printf-epochtime-shows-wrong-values/64632176#comment114276774_64630721)

Best to zero out `epochtime` first to initialize all members - there may be more than 9.

```
struct tm epochtime = {0};
epochtime.tm_mday = 19;
epochtime.tm_mon = 10 - 1;       // Months since January
epochtime.tm_year = 2002 - 1900; // Year since 1900
epochtime.tm_isdst = -1;         // Let system daylight daylight time for that date
epochdate = mktime(&epochtime);  // epochtime is assumed here to be a local time
```

Comment: `tm_isdst` is set by `mktime` regardless.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli All of the members of `struct tm` may be set by `mktime()` to bring them into primary range.  To initialize `.tm_isdst` to zero (as in your answer)  forces  `mktime()` to assess `epochtime` as _standard time_ - even in the summer.  Setting it to -1, allows `mktime()` to assess `epochtime` as a daylight time with summer timestamps, after which, that member is set to 0,1.